# Word that means "First Among Equals"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to come up with a word that would describe someone who is the first among equals. I did a quick search on the term on Google, and didn't come up with anything really satisfactory.

Comment: What's wrong with just saying "first among equals"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about "preeminent"? I think it fits your definition.

Comment: That's what I was going to say.

Answer (score 5):

The only single words that I can think of that have ever been used to mean that have lost the meaning through the somewhat natural process where the "among equals" part becomes more or less of a joke: *prince* and its Latin root *princeps*.

In phrases, *first citizen* is commonly employed, and the plain Latin for first among equals, *primus inter pares*, has some history behind it.

Comment: I was also going to suggest *primus inter pares*, especially if you want to look all fancy.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest "primus" as Chaos has already done.
Alternatively, "principal" could be appropriate in some circumstances - although I imagine this could be confused with the use as "senior teacher within a school" in the US.

Comment: Aside: At least in big public schools the principal rarely actually teaches anymore. They are administrators, which make the appellation a little out of date.